# Unable to do upper case in bootstrap editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I used bootstrap editable function and it worked fine.But I want that editable text in uppercase always.I did not understand how to to do that.Please help me.

```
<td>
<a href="#" id="address" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $teacherid ?>" data-url="profileeditdb.php"   data-title="Enter Your Address">
<?php
    if (!empty($teacheraddr)) {
        echo $teacheraddr;
    }else {
        echo "";
    }
?>  
</a>
</td>
<script>
 $("#address").editable();
</script>
```

This is my code...Please help me.

Comment: Do you want to display the value in uppercase? Or send the data to your server in uppercase?

Comment: no I want to write upper case with out pressing capslock.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP strtoupper() function.
If you use strtoupper() function then you code should look like

```
<td>
<a href="#" id="address" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $teacherid ?>" 
data-url="profileeditdb.php"   data-title="Enter Your Address">
<?php
if (!empty($teacheraddr)) {
    echo strtoupper($teacheraddr);
}else {
    echo "";
}
?>  
</a>
</td>
<script>
 $("#address").editable();
</script>
```

Comment: This won't prevent users from typing in lowercase.

Comment: I want to write uppercase not display. Thanks